# Unmount NFS folders on wlan0 with pre-down

Tags: shutdown, freeze, nfs, ubuntu-12.10, wifi

I'm working on this machine (Ubuntu 12.10) that needs to connect to a NAS via wlan.
/etc/fstab is configured with **nfs auto** and the directory is mounted correctly when the wlan is connected.
BUT
the computer won't shutdown and hangs waiting for the directory to be unmounted.
I did some research and the most common solution is mounting the directories with the **soft,sync** options but I'm not too sure about using **soft**.
I think this problem can be fixed with just unmounting the directory before bringing down the interface. 
So, I was thinking about using the pre-down function in /etc/network/interfaces, but I don't know how to write it correctly.

```
iface wlan0 inet manual
  pre-down /path/to/script_to_unmount_stuff.sh
```

Where script_to_unmount_stuff.sh would look like

```
umount -l /path/to/folder1
umount -l /path/to/folder2
```

Can something like this work?
Any other suggestion?
Thanks!